# How do I export certain specific data from one excel WB to another?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my table.

[image: Table]

So I will keep on adding data as we receive more persons. With that I would like to export only certain data from this table to another WB. In this case, I would only like to export the info in columns Person, Info, ID and Conc. I don't even know where to start. I don't know if this is possible but if I select a few rows (ie person 1), can that information I'm interested in (columns of interest) be extracted only from the selected rows into an open work book in specific locations or maybe different tabs? The goal is that I want to keep all my data compiled in this master WS, and I would also like to keep a separate file for each person in their respective folder. Hopefully anyone will be able to help and thank you in advance. Let me know if this is impossible. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast answer.

Open new WB:

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1()

    'Adding New Workbook
    Workbooks.Add

    'Saving the Workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\WorkbookName.xls"

    'OR
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\WorkbookName1.xls"

End Sub
```

Copy the necessary columns. To make it easy, I recommand to record a "search" macro for the relevant column name.
Go to the code and edit it as you like, very easy. Now copy the whole column.

In your code, go to the new WB, and paste the column.

Do the same for all necessary columns.

Save the new WB and close it.

If it's too complicated, I will write the code for you.

Comment: Thank you! I used your suggestion and a few lines from another link. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)